# How can I continuously check whether a file gets deleted and if it didn't get deleted try again

Tags: c#, file

In my current project I'm facing random errors complaining the file in question is being used by other processes.

Sometime it acts fast and everything is just fine, some other times it won't work and keeps giving me the error

> The file is being used by another process

So I thought I place the delete method inside a `try-catch` and in the catch I have some kind of loop which would try to delete the file or even better: unlocks it and makes it ready for being deleted.

I have no idea if inside that loop I get another exception, and how to manage that. How can I find a solution to detach that process from the file, and make it ready for deletion?

### Update

This is my code at the moment:

```
 private void Test(string imagePath)
 {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(imagePath))
            {
                pictureBoxExistingPicture.Visible = true;
                labelnew.Visible = true;
                labelold.Visible = true;
                pictureBoxExistingPicture.Image = ImageUtility.SafeLoadImage(imagePath);

                if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to overwrite the existing image?", "warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    pictureBoxExistingPicture.Image = Properties.Resources._default;//restore default

                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            File.Delete(imagePath);
                            break;
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                        }
                    }

                    pictureBoxHonarjo.Image.Save(imagePath);
                }
                else
                {
                    pictureBoxHonarjo.Image = ImageUtility.SafeLoadImage(imagePath);//restore original image
                }

                pictureBoxExistingPicture.Visible = false;
                labelnew.Visible = false;
                labelold.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

in the current context of the subject, i need to say that if the user wishes to replace the image, it should get done , and it shouldn't take a long time nor should it fail to do so.So basically when someone tries to change a picture,It must get changed in a fraction of the time.

And for the `SafeLoadImage` function, here is my implementation:

```
public class ImageUtility
{
   public static byte[] ImageToBytes(string FilePath, int FileLength)
   {
      FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      BinaryReader breader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
      return breader.ReadBytes(FileLength);
    }

    public static Image SafeLoadImage(string imagePath)
    {
        byte[] image_byte;
        Image image;
        FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(imagePath);
        image_byte = ImageUtility.ImageToBytes(imagePath, (int)fileinfo.Length);
        image = ImageUtility.BytesToImage(image_byte);
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the `try catch` block within the loop and `break` if successful.

Comment: I think you need to figure out why the file is locked.  It could be locked for a good reason.  Use this to help find out which process has the file locked.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: @hmjd:Thanks,but thats not a good solution,now i am in an infinite loop which i have no idea when it is going to end!

Comment: Justin Harvi: i have no clue how im supposed to work with that? im dealing with the picture box , and most probably the process using my file Is my project itself , the catch is i have no idea which part of it is using that!

Comment: I think the issue is that you aren't releasing your file lock in your ImageUtility (you need to close/dispose the reader). Check my answer and see if that sorts your problem out and consider using the `using` block when the target type implements IDisposable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageUtility.ImageToBytes` doesn't dispose the FileStream when finished

Could it be this that's locking the file?

```
public static byte[] ImageToBytes(string FilePath, int FileLength) 
{ 
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 
    BinaryReader breader = new BinaryReader(fileStream); 
    return breader.ReadBytes(FileLength); 
}
```

Consider the `using` statement which will free resources after execution exits the code block (it wraps IDisposable and calls the dispose method for you):

```
public static byte[] ImageToBytes(string FilePath, int FileLength) 
{ 
    using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
    {
        BinaryReader breader = new BinaryReader(fileStream); 
        return breader.ReadBytes(FileLength); 
    }
}
```

This may be the reason your file is locked.

Of course if someone else is locking your file, then this might be useless :) but I suspect that these are image files you have created/are processing

Comment: Thank you .It seems that was the cause and after doing your suggestion it now wroks flawlessly :)

Answer (score 1):

OK

so you have some pseudo code such as:

```
success = false
while not success
..try
..  delete file
..  success = true
..catch
..  wait a second
while end
```

You can add a retry counter so it doesnt endlessly loop etc too with any luck you can guess where.

I have deliberately not included code, as you gave none of your own, but given you a template of something to try

Answer (score 1):

here a loop to try to delete file:

```
protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
```

{ 
    FileStream stream = null;

```
try 
{ 
    stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None); 
} 
catch (IOException) 
{ 
    //the file is unavailable because it is: 
    //still being written to 
    //or being processed by another thread 
    //or does not exist (has already been processed) 
    return true; 
} 
finally 
{ 
    if (stream != null) 
        stream.Close(); 
} 

//file is not locked 
return false;
```

}

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("PathToTheFile"); 
while (IsFileLocked(file)) 
    Thread.Sleep(1000); 
file.Delete();
```

You can also use Process explorer to know which process access to file http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Thank you. but it really is'nt that different from the same scenario suggested by the first comment and being used in the application at the moment. i need to identify the problem at runtime and eliminate it .While your solution works finally , it takes time in case of trying to delete the file if its being used by other processes. i need a faster approach to solve this problem if one exits .

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution with MessageBox:

```
bool deleted= false;
while(!deleted)
{
 try
  {
    File.Delete("path to file");                                 
    deleted = true;
  }
 catch 
  {
    MessageBox.Show("You can't delete file. Close file and press 'OK'");
    deleted = false; 
  }
}
```